# Determine Array Length Before Compiling

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation, arduino, preprocessor

I try to setup a simple access control mechanism in Arduino and C++. The single password for access is known at compilation time and looks something like this

```
const unsigned int PASSWORD[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

To compare the user input with `PASSWORD`, I need several other arrays (not all of them with the same data type) that have the same number of elements as `PASSWORD`.

At the moment, the only way I can think of to achieve this is to have a second constant variable

```
const unsigned int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 5;
```

However, having the user enter a password and the same password's length in the settings seems like an unnecessary redundancy to me.

Therefore, my question is, if there is a way to inform the compiler about `PASSWORD`'s length and to use this length as a variable in the code, without having the user counting the elements herself?

Comment: Simple `const unsigned int PASSWORD_LENGTH = sizeof(PASSWORD) / sizeof(int);`

Comment: `sizeof(PASSWORD) / sizeof(*PASSWORD)` is a bit more generic. Since we're talking about arduino you could even make a macro out of that.

Comment: would a second array `unsigned long COMP_ARRAY[sizeof(PASSWORD) / sizeof(int)];` even compile?

Comment: They are compile time constants, so yes.

Comment: okay, in that case I understand this question is considered stupid ;)

Comment: actually it was not ment to be stupid, because it is a bit difficult for me to share this information with different classes in my code. However, I have to admit this was not part of my question

Comment: It's likely you'd want a header then that has your `const unsigned password_length` in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::size()`.

This will help : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Comment: May not be available with OP's compiler.